# Curl PHP, pass http2-prior-knowledge to the PHP module

Tags: php, curl, http2

I'm not sure if this is possible at all but I need to make PHP Curl call using this flag from the command line:

```
--http2-prior-knowledge
```

Now from the documentation it is possible only to do something like:

`CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0`

which is not my case.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Support for `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE` was added to PHP in [this commit](http://lxr.php.net/history/PHP-7.1/ext/curl/interface.c#3c92f113) in April 2016. Introduced in PHP 7.0.7 according to [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).